# Should I design with "N" parts or newer parts?

Tags: transistors, analog, diodes

I noticed there are parts with "N" in the part name, for example the 1N4148 diode and the 2N2222 transistor, etc. What is the history of these parts? Where did they come from and why do they have these part numbers? Are they somewhat obsolete, like the discrete digital logic parts? Manufacturers seem to be coming out with new parts, are they necessarily improvements over the old "N" parts?

Answer (score 8):

The 2Nxxxxx designation was a industry wide designation that was derived by the organization that became the EIA.  While different manufacturers had their own 2N number, with others second sourcing some parts, they maintained a common naming scheme for these parts across the industry.

The concept of obsolescence for discreet parts doesn't fit.  Yes, certain parts will have superior Hfe (for example) or handle higher current (as another example), but a part is the right part if the specifications fit your needs (performance, cost etc.) regardless of it's history, age or process technology.  The only real measure of obsolescence is whether or not you can buy the parts to support manufacturing.

On Edit: The standard is Jedec 370B - which was a RETMA (Radio Electron Televsion manufacturers Assoc.) -> EIA -> JEDEC standard based upon the old tube/valve designators from the RMA (Radio Manf. Associations).  N designates crystal rectifier.

Standard is downloadable [here](http://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/results) as JESD370B.

Answer (score 8):

The number before "N" refers to the number of junctions, or the number of electrodes - 1. So all the 1N parts have 2 electrodes - diodes, zeners and so on. The 2N parts are universally 3-electrode parts, either bipolar or FET transistors. There are a few 3N parts - four-electrode devices or tetrodes to the older engineers - dual-gate MOSFETs being the commonest.

Anyone ever see a 4N device?

The designation doesn't really indicate the age of the device so much as the geographical region of origin. 2N2222 parts seem exotic here but BC107s and BC548s are common as muck.

Comment: [4N25 optocouplers](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf) are pretty ubiquitous, and inexpensive, at least in India. They really should have named those 5Nxxx: 2N for the LED and another 3N for the phototransistor! :-)

Comment: Ooh, forgot about optocouplers. 5 electrodes, 4N is correct. Any 5N devices then? 7N for an 8-pin opamp?

Comment: Well, there is also the [6n137 optocoupler](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/6N/6N137.pdf) that Fairchild Semi still sells - yes, it does have 6 functional leads, so 6n is legit. Besides, the company Unisonic Tech went pretty crazy with the nomenclature, but I wouldn't really consider their part numbers valid use of the xN pattern: They have everything from 5N50 and [5N80 N-MOSFET](http://www.unisonic.com.tw/datasheet/5N80.pdf), through 7N, 8N, and even [9N50 MOSFETs](http://www.unisonic.com.tw/datasheet/9N50.pdf). All of those are 3-terminal parts, evidently the numbering is rubbish.

Comment: I also vaguely recollect some other (legitimate multi-terminal parts, not Unisonic) 5N and 7N devices, all optocouplers I believe, but since I can't remember the complete part numbers, I can't locate relevant datasheets. Legitimate 8Nxx, I don't think so.